# linux "lessPATH" similar to $CDPATH and $PATH

Tags: linux, path

I like the flexibility and how easy it is to execute commands from any directory in **$PATH variable or $CDPATH** to change directory.

But is there an easy way to "less or open a file" from a **list of directories** you often visit.

Say you have log files in a different dir and other frequently visited directories in another. A `less file1` command should look for the file1 in a list of directories defined like a $PATH  or $CDPATH variable.

Comment: this sounds like it belongs on [su].

Comment: @ Daniel A. White, It can be done in pure shell scripting, though

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you look for an existing solution but if you use bash you can write a function than has exactly this behavior :

put in `~/.bashrc`:

```
less2()
{
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'Missing filename ("less --help" for help)'
    return 1
  fi

  if [ "$1" == "--help" ]
  then
    less $1
    return 1
  fi

  OLDIFS=$IFS
  IFS=':'
  if [ -z $LESSPATH ]; then
    SEARCH_PATHS=.
  else
    SEARCH_PATHS=.:${LESSPATH}
  fi

  for dir in $SEARCH_PATHS
  do
    if test -e "$dir/$1"
    then
       less "$dir/$1"
       IFS=$OLDIFS
       return
    fi
  done
  IFS=$OLDIFS
  echo "$1: No such file or directory"
}
```

You need to execute `source ~/.bashrc` in order to get less2 in your bash.

**How to use the script**

By defaults it looks for files in a current directory. If you set the enviroment variable LESSPATH `less2` will look for a file first in the current directory and then if it is not there it will look for the file in all the directories in `$LESSPATH`. `less2` is a function in a current bash process so it is not necessary to export `LESSPATH`, but of course you can also export `LESSPATH`.

```
$ less2 my_file.log

$ LESSPATH=path1:path2:path3
$ less2 my_other_file.log
```

Comment: thank you. less2 script looks right. but what do u need to do in .bashrc?

Comment: less2 is a bash function (http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html), as you see. So you need to put its text in .bashrc. I need to fix some problems with find yet!!!

Comment: i saw you remove find command..

Comment: In bash it is correct to check if a file exists with `-e`: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html. It is even faster since no process is launched

Comment: Awesome.. it works. Only thing I changed in the script is to replace $LESS2HOME with my directories (Colon separated). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I added $LESS2HOME in a script in order to have a easy way to change a set of search directories just by setting an enviroment variable. You can combine your approach with mine using bash parameter substitution: SEARCH_PATHS=.:${LESS2HOME:-/your-defualt-folders}. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html